# Javascript accordion menu open when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, accordion

I am extremely new to coding, especially Javascript. I recently found a tutorial that I got to work for an accordion menu, but I am unable to understand how to get the drop downs closed when the page loads. Currently, all of the drop downs are open when the page loads. I tried looking at other solutions but I just don't understand the code fully yet. Thank you so much!

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
 $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
    }
    else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
    }
});

});


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
```

on line 4 with

```
$('#cssmenu li.active').removeClass('open').children('ul').hide();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

You triggered expand action only on click. Just must set the first state on DOM elements.

```
<div style="display: none;"></div>
```

Or by default controled "closed" class name instead of "open"